# If statement comparing a calculated result to a number returns false even if they're the same

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, if-statement

- Number field "QuantiteStockageConteneur" = 7922.55
- Currency field "TauxStockageConteneur" = 0.28
- Currency field "StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube" = 2218.31

[image: Fields screenshot]

I have tried:

```
=IF([QuantiteStockageConteneur]*[TauxStockageConteneur]=[StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube],TRUE,FALSE)
```

Original language (copy & paste):

```
=SI([QuantiteStockageConteneur]*[TauxStockageConteneur]=[StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube];VRAI;FAUX)
```

It returns **FALSE**.

So I wondered what is the actual value returned. So I made a calculated column taking the same formula.

It returns the same value.

[image: A calculated column returning the result of the previous calculation returns the same value as the number I entered in the form]

So I tried:

```
=IF([CalculTestStockageConteneur]=[StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube],TRUE,FALSE)
```

Original language (copy & paste):

```
=SI([CalculTestStockageConteneur]=[StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube];VRAI;FAUX)
```

Still *FALSE*.

[image: The columns have the same value, yet the if statement returns false]

The problem **is not yes/no**. I tried having it return 1 or 0 as a number calculated field, it returned 0 (FALSE).

I tried "OUI" ("YES") and "NON" ("NO") in place of VRAI (TRUE) and FAUX (FALSE), same thing.

It's simple, yet it doesn't work. Any idea?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little tweaking you need to do in the formula as it's not able to compare the exact values.
It worked for me while doing the Round up of the values. So, you can try the below one -

```
Round([QuantiteStockageConteneur]*[TauxStockageConteneur],0)=Round([StockageDeConteneur_ParPiedCube],0)
```

Don't need to put the if as well if the return type is Yes/No only.

Comment: Thanks, there's a slight risk the results could be different but it's close enough. So, if-statements cannot compare floating-point numbers?